# Re-ordering data in form index with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm brand new to programming and trying to solve a minor problem.  I've just created a database in ruby on rails.  I want my forms for the DB to be as user-friendly as possible.  By default the form index puts new data at the bottom of the page.  This is inconvenient because if a user wants to verify quickly that he/she has entered data correctly the user has to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page.  Is there a way that I can change the default to display the new data at the top of the table in my index view.

Any tips will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def index
  @objects = Object.order 'created_at DESC'
end
```

Welcome to the world of programming!

This sorts object by the time they were created.  Replace Object with whatever your model is called.  There's probably a line like Object.all somewhere.

Rails has many guides to get you started: http://guides.rubyonrails.org

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I think I'm really going to show how new I am by asking this question, but is this a migration that I run?

Comment: Nope, just swapping one line of code for another.  Check in objects_controller, again swapping "objects" for your model.  This will be in a folder under {your project}/app/controllers.  More on that: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm

Comment: Note: migrations are typically used to update your database structure -- i.e. adding a column, creating a table, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much!  It worked perfectly.  Thanks for the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Lets you have a table called 'posts' and Post model is being used for it.

In the posts_controller.rb

```
def index
  #@posts = Post.all
  #if we are applying the above query it will fetch all the posts order by id in ascending order.
  # you want to show the post which has been created recently. for that you need to change the order of your query. @GoGoCarl has suggested the same taking created_at in account. We can also achieve it taking id field as well.

  @posts = Post.order("id DESC") 

  # This above syntax execute 
  # SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` ORDER BY id DESC. Now you ca get your way out.
end
```

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of another. :)  Though, technically, order by date gets you the "real" order, whereas the ID is only coincidentally ordered chronologically.  But for 99% of projects, I'm willing to take that risk!  Some developers also modify created_at and updated_at in their views (i.e. blogs), so sorting this way would allow for those changes to be reflected.